# Layered or Facet bar plot with label values in Altair

Tags: python, plot, altair

I'm trying to create a simple bar plot (with multiple columns for a specific field):

```
bars = alt.Chart(df_probing).mark_bar(stroke='transparent').encode(
    alt.X('model_name:N', scale=alt.Scale(rangeStep=12), axis=alt.Axis(title='')),
    alt.Y('acc:Q', axis=alt.Axis(title='Accuracy', grid=False)),
    color=alt.Color('model_name:N'),
    column='task_name:N'
).configure_view(
    stroke='transparent'
).configure_axis(
    domainWidth=0.8
)
```

Now, this plot works well, but when I try to add the value labels on top of the bars [like this](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/bar_chart_with_labels.html):

```
text = bars.mark_text(
    align='center',
).encode(
    text='acc:Q'
)

bars + text
```

It throws the following error:

```
ValueError: Objects with "config" attribute cannot be used within LayerChart. Consider defining the config attribute in the LayerChart object instead.
```

How can bar labels be added to each bar in the bar plot on facet/layered plots ?

Comment: If you remove the .`configure_view` & the `.configure_axis` calls, it will help. I don't have your data frame, but when I tried it without the `column` (stacked bar) the text did render.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `configure_*` methods only work for the top-level chart; the error is attempting to tell you this, but it's not as clear as it could be.

The solution is to move the configuration to the top-level object; that is, do something like this:

```
bars = alt.Chart(df_probing).mark_bar(stroke='transparent').encode(
    alt.X('model_name:N', title='', scale=alt.Scale(rangeStep=12)),
    alt.Y('acc:Q', title='Accuracy', axis=alt.Axis(grid=False)),
    color='model_name:N',
    column='task_name:N'
) 

text = bars.mark_text(
    align='center',
).encode(
    text='acc:Q'
)

alt.layer(bars, text).configure_view(
    stroke='transparent'
).configure_axis(
    domainWidth=0.8
)
```

Comment: Based on your code in [git-issue#920](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/920#issuecomment-395287144), perhaps the column specification `column='task_name:N'` should move out of  `bars` to inside `alt.layer()`