# How to stack charts in Altair

Tags: pandas, altair

I have a series of charts that I want to put together in Altair to create a dashboard.

The first is national stats Top left. Let's call it top_left

[image]

The second is at regional level. I want this beneath the first - there are going to be two more panels but I'll work on them later.

[image]

I'll call that bottom_left.

I've learned that the

```
top_left & bottom_left
```

should lead to one on top of the other in Altair.

But I get the error:

```
ValueError: Objects with "config" attribute cannot be used within VConcatChart. Consider defining the config attribute in the VConcatChart object instead.
```

What does this mean and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50729946/12355337) post should answer your question.

You did not provide any code for the two example charts but it seems at least one of them uses one of the "config_*" methods. So what you have to do is remove that config from the chart, combine/arrange your charts and then do the config on that combined chart object.

Comment: Thank for that. I got there in the end. More to the point, I love your profile name.